# How do I draw a thing on the mouse location when I click and add it to a queue?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I want a face to be added to a queue everytime I click inside the form. It should then be drawn where I click every time I click. These faces are defined in a seperate class shown below:

```
class Face
{        
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;       
    private int lenght = 0;
    private int height = 0;
    private int diameter = 0;        

    public Face(int x, int y, int lenght, int height , int diameter)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Lenght = lenght ;
        Height = height ;
        Diameter = diameter;
    }


    public int X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set { x = value; }
    }

    public int Y
    {
        get { return y; }
        set { y = value ; }
    }

    public int Lenght 
    {
        get { return lenght ; }
        set { lenght = value; }
    }

    public int Height 
    {
        get { return height; }
        set { height = value; }
    }

    public int Diameter
    {
        get { return diameter; }
        set { diameter = value; }
    }


    public void DrawLeftEye(Graphics g)
    {
        g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), X+5, Y+5, Lenght, Height);
    }

    public void DrawRightEye(Graphics g)
    {
        g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), X + 11, Y + 5, Lenght, Height);
    }

    public void DrawFace(Graphics g)
    {
        g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Pink), X, Y, Diameter, Diameter);
    }
```

So far I've done this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Queue<Face> faces= new Queue<Face>();


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        int x = 20;
        int y = 70;       
        int lenght= 5;
        int height= 5;
        int diameter = 20; 

        face = new Face (x, y, lenght, height, diameter);

        faces.Enqueue(face);
    }        

    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {            

        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        face.DrawFace(g);    
        face.DrawLeftEye(g);
        face.DrawRightEye(g);
        Invalidate(); 

    }                
}
```

If it isn't obvious I'm kind of lost on how to do this. I have no idea how to get the location of the mouse, yet alone how I should add the face to a queue and then draw it.

A little help is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the mouse position (relative to one of your elements) with

```
eventArgs.GetPosition(WhateverElementYouLike);
```

Since the Queue would be empty after every single `OnRender`, you might want to replace it with a List.

```
private List<Face> faces= new List<Face>();
```

So in your case it would be something similar to this:

```
protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
{           
    Point position = e.GetPosition(this); 
    int x = (int)e.X;
    int y = (int)e.Y;       

    faces.Add(new Face (x, y, 5, 5, 20));
    InvalidateVisual();
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    foreach(Face face in faces)
    {
        face.DrawFace(g);    
        face.DrawLeftEye(g);
        face.DrawRightEye(g);
    }
}
```